# How to build aosp 6.0 img and run emulator with the img on mac m1 device?

Tags: emulation, android-source

How to build aosp 6.0 img and run emulator with the img on mac m1 device ?

**In a word, I want to compile my own android 6.0 image and then use this image to run the emulator on mac m1**

I'm what to learn aosp . Now i got aosp-6.0.0_r1 and aosp-6.0.0_r6 source code . I can build the code success , and got the result img files , on intel64 linux device .

- on intel64 devide the build result imgs can be use by emulator to run .

My build enviroment is

- Debian12
- [Docker container ubuntu 14.04](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/build/+/refs/heads/main/tools/docker/)

The build result of aosp-6.0.0_r1 :

- when on docker build success , i exit docker .
- on debian my `aosp.zshrc` config is this . **"attachments `aosp.zshrc.sh`"**
- ```
      # AOSP source path evn

      export AOSP_ROOT=/Volumes/Beyourself/AOSP

      export AOSP_5=$AOSP_ROOT/android-5.0.1_r1
      export AOSP_5_OUT=$AOSP_ROOT/android-5.0.1_r1.tmp

      export AOSP_6=$AOSP_ROOT/android-6.0.0_r1
      export AOSP_6_OUT=$AOSP_ROOT/android-6.0.0_r1.tmp

      export AOSP_6_R6=$AOSP_ROOT/android-6.0.0_r6
      export AOSP_6_R6_OUT=$AOSP_ROOT/android-6.0.0_r6.tmp

      # export AOSP_PATH=$AOSP_6
      # export AOSP_OUT=$AOSP_6_OUT
      #export AOSP_PATH=$AOSP_6_R6
      #export AOSP_OUT=$AOSP_6_R6_OUT

      # alias source-aosp-build-envsetup.sh='source $AOSP_PATH/build/envsetup.sh'
      alias repoAlias='python3 $AOSP_ROOT/bin/repo'

      function source-aosp-build-envsetup() {
          # AOSP build cache setting  : https://source.android.com/source/initializing?hl=zh-cn#optimizing-a-build-environment
          curPath=$(pwd)
          if [ "$curPath" = "$AOSP_PATH" ]; then
              echo -e "\n You are on AOSP path:  $AOSP_PATH "
              echo "Config build cache.  "
              export USE_CCACHE=1
              export CCACHE_DIR=$AOSP_OUT/build_ccache
              prebuilts/misc/linux-x86/ccache/ccache -M 100G    
          fi

          echo -e "\n>>>> source $AOSP_PATH/build/envsetup.sh"
          source $AOSP_PATH/build/envsetup.sh
      }


      # When config the build result env config , 
      # just emulatorAliasXxx we can run the result emulator with we build imgs . 

      export ANDROID_PRODUCT_OUT=$AOSP_OUT/build_out/target/product/generic
      export OUT=$ANDROID_PRODUCT_OUT
      export ANDROID_BUILD_TOP=$AOSP_PATH

      alias emulatorAliasMac='$AOSP_PATH/prebuilts/android-emulator/darwin-x86_64/emulator'
      alias emulatorAliasLinux='$AOSP_PATH/prebuilts/android-emulator/linux-x86_64/emulator'
  ```
- On intel Debian devide , i can run emulator with build out imgs success .
- On Mac m1 i can't
- My lunch cmd : `lunch aosp_arm-eng`

I know , on Android studio , we can download android 6 emulator image files . And the images can run success by emulator .

- **I what to imitate it to build 6.0 imgs by my self , and run emulator with my self imgs . **

This is the images download log : **attachments `android-studio-download-android6-imgs.log`**

- ```
  Preparing "Install ARM 64 v8a System Image API 23 (revision 7)".
  Downloading https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/android/arm64-v8a-23_r07.zip
  "Install ARM 64 v8a System Image API 23 (revision 7)" ready.
  Preparing "Install Intel x86 Atom System Image API 23 (revision 10)".
  Downloading https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/android/x86-23_r10.zip
  "Install Intel x86 Atom System Image API 23 (revision 10)" ready.
  Preparing "Install ARM EABI v7a System Image API 23 (revision 6)".
  Downloading https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/android/armeabi-v7a-23_r06.zip
  "Install ARM EABI v7a System Image API 23 (revision 6)" ready.
  Preparing "Install Intel x86_64 Atom System Image API 23 (revision 10)".
  Downloading https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/android/x86_64-23_r10.zip
  "Install Intel x86_64 Atom System Image API 23 (revision 10)" ready.
  Installing ARM 64 v8a System Image in /Volumes/Beyourself/dev_tools/dev_kit/android_sdk/system-images/android-23/default/arm64-v8a
  "Install ARM 64 v8a System Image API 23 (revision 7)" complete.
  "Install ARM 64 v8a System Image API 23 (revision 7)" finished.
  Installing Intel x86 Atom System Image in /Volumes/Beyourself/dev_tools/dev_kit/android_sdk/system-images/android-23/default/x86
  "Install Intel x86 Atom System Image API 23 (revision 10)" complete.
  "Install Intel x86 Atom System Image API 23 (revision 10)" finished.
  Installing ARM EABI v7a System Image in /Volumes/Beyourself/dev_tools/dev_kit/android_sdk/system-images/android-23/default/armeabi-v7a
  "Install ARM EABI v7a System Image API 23 (revision 6)" complete.
  "Install ARM EABI v7a System Image API 23 (revision 6)" finished.
  Installing Intel x86_64 Atom System Image in /Volumes/Beyourself/dev_tools/dev_kit/android_sdk/system-images/android-23/default/x86_64
  "Install Intel x86_64 Atom System Image API 23 (revision 10)" complete.
  "Install Intel x86_64 Atom System Image API 23 (revision 10)" finished.
  ```

I run emulator with [armeabi-v7a-23_r06](https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/android/armeabi-v7a-23_r06.zip) images , success . On android setting app i got build info is :

- *Android version* : 6.0
- *Build number* : sdk_phone_armv7-userdebug 6.0 MASTER 3079352 test-key .
- **attachments: `android-download-emulator-imgs-run-result.jpeg`**
- [image]

How to find the code branch `MASTER 3079352` , I don't know . Because aosp source are many repository .

- The images name `armeabi-v7a-23_r06` i guess the aosp branch is `android-6.0.0_r6`
- Then i download the code and lunch cmd is : `lunch sdk_phone_armv7-userdebug`
- `build` success on docker ubuntu os .
- on debian12 `alias emulatorAliasLinux='$AOSP_PATH/prebuilts/android-emulator/linux-x86_64/emulator'`

  - I run emulator success by the build result imgs , use cmd `emulatorAliasLinux`
- the same aosp and build result copy to mac m1 device

  - env `alias emulatorAliasMac='$AOSP_PATH/prebuilts/android-emulator/darwin-x86_64/emulator'`
  - execute `emulatorAliasMac`
  - the emulator just show Android LOGO , not start success . **attachments: `aosp6.0.0_r6_build_imgs_run_on_mac_m1_just_show_logo.png`**
  - [image]
  - this is `emulatorAliasMac` log : **attachments : `4.emulator.just.aosp.content.log`**
  - ```
    emulator: found Android build root: /Volumes/MacOs_disk/AOSP/android-6.0.0_r6
    emulator: found Android build out:  /Volumes/MacOs_disk/AOSP/android-6.0.0_r6.tmp/build_out/target/product/generic
    emulator: Read property file at /Volumes/MacOs_disk/AOSP/android-6.0.0_r6.tmp/build_out/target/product/generic/system/build.prop
    emulator: Cannot find boot properties file: /Volumes/MacOs_disk/AOSP/android-6.0.0_r6.tmp/build_out/target/product/generic/boot.prop

    emulator: Found target API sdkVersion: 23

    emulator: virtual device has no config file - no problem
    emulator: using core hw config path: /Volumes/MacOs_disk/AOSP/android-6.0.0_r6.tmp/build_out/target/product/generic/hardware-qemu.ini
    emulator: found skin-specific hardware.ini: /Volumes/MacOs_disk/AOSP/android-6.0.0_r6/development/tools/emulator/skins/HVGA/hardware.ini
    emulator: autoconfig: -skin HVGA
    emulator: autoconfig: -skindir /Volumes/MacOs_disk/AOSP/android-6.0.0_r6/development/tools/emulator/skins
    emulator: found skin-specific hardware.ini: /Volumes/MacOs_disk/AOSP/android-6.0.0_r6/development/tools/emulator/skins/HVGA/hardware.ini
    emulator: keyset loaded from: /Users/tom/.android/default.keyset
    emulator: trying to load skin file '/Volumes/MacOs_disk/AOSP/android-6.0.0_r6/development/tools/emulator/skins/HVGA/layout'
    emulator: skin network speed: 'full'
    emulator: skin network delay: 'none'
    emulator: autoconfig: -kernel /Volumes/MacOs_disk/AOSP/android-6.0.0_r6/prebuilts/qemu-kernel/arm/kernel-qemu-armv7
    emulator: Auto-detect: Kernel image requires legacy device naming scheme.
    emulator: Auto-detect: Kernel does not support YAFFS2 partitions.
    emulator: autoconfig: -ramdisk /Volumes/MacOs_disk/AOSP/android-6.0.0_r6.tmp/build_out/target/product/generic/ramdisk.img
    emulator: autoconfig: -sysdir /Volumes/MacOs_disk/AOSP/android-6.0.0_r6.tmp/build_out/target/product/generic
    emulator: Using initial system image: /Volumes/MacOs_disk/AOSP/android-6.0.0_r6.tmp/build_out/target/product/generic/system.img
    emulator: WARNING: system partition size adjusted to match image file (1536 MB > 200 MB)

    emulator: autoconfig: -data /Volumes/MacOs_disk/AOSP/android-6.0.0_r6.tmp/build_out/target/product/generic/userdata-qemu.img
    emulator: autoconfig: -initdata /Volumes/MacOs_disk/AOSP/android-6.0.0_r6.tmp/build_out/target/product/generic/userdata.img
    emulator: WARNING: data partition size adjusted to match image file (550 MB > 200 MB)

    emulator: autoconfig: -cache /Volumes/MacOs_disk/AOSP/android-6.0.0_r6.tmp/build_out/target/product/generic/cache.img
    emulator: Physical RAM size: 512MB

    emulator: GPU emulation is disabled
    emulator: WARNING: CPU acceleration only works with x86/x86_64 system images.
    emulator: Auto-config: -qemu -cpu cortex-a8
    Content of hardware configuration file:
      hw.cpu.arch = arm
      hw.cpu.model = cortex-a8
      hw.ramSize = 512
      hw.screen = touch
      hw.mainKeys = yes
      hw.trackBall = yes
      hw.keyboard = no
      hw.keyboard.lid = no
      hw.keyboard.charmap = qwerty2
      hw.dPad = yes
      hw.gsmModem = yes
      hw.gps = yes
      hw.battery = yes
      hw.accelerometer = yes
      hw.audioInput = yes
      hw.audioOutput = yes
      hw.sdCard = yes
      disk.cachePartition = yes
      disk.cachePartition.path = /Volumes/MacOs_disk/AOSP/android-6.0.0_r6.tmp/build_out/target/product/generic/cache.img
      disk.cachePartition.size = 66m
      hw.lcd.width = 320
      hw.lcd.height = 480
      hw.lcd.depth = 16
      hw.lcd.density = 160
      hw.lcd.backlight = yes
      hw.gpu.enabled = no
      hw.initialOrientation = portrait
      hw.camera.back = emulated
      hw.camera.front = none
      vm.heapSize = 48
      hw.sensors.proximity = yes
      hw.sensors.magnetic_field = yes
      hw.sensors.orientation = yes
      hw.sensors.temperature = yes
      hw.useext4 = yes
      kernel.path = /Volumes/MacOs_disk/AOSP/android-6.0.0_r6/prebuilts/qemu-kernel/arm/kernel-qemu-armv7
      kernel.parameters =  androidboot.hardware=goldfish android.checkjni=1
      kernel.newDeviceNaming = no
      kernel.supportsYaffs2 = no
      disk.ramdisk.path = /Volumes/MacOs_disk/AOSP/android-6.0.0_r6.tmp/build_out/target/product/generic/ramdisk.img
      disk.systemPartition.initPath = /Volumes/MacOs_disk/AOSP/android-6.0.0_r6.tmp/build_out/target/product/generic/system.img
      disk.systemPartition.size = 1536m
      disk.dataPartition.path = /Volumes/MacOs_disk/AOSP/android-6.0.0_r6.tmp/build_out/target/product/generic/userdata-qemu.img
      disk.dataPartition.size = 550m
      avd.name = <build>
    .
    QEMU options list:
    emulator: argv[00] = "/Volumes/MacOs_disk/AOSP/android-6.0.0_r6/prebuilts/android-emulator/darwin-x86_64/emulator64-arm"
    emulator: argv[01] = "-android-hw"
    emulator: argv[02] = "/Volumes/MacOs_disk/AOSP/android-6.0.0_r6.tmp/build_out/target/product/generic/hardware-qemu.ini"
    Concatenated QEMU options:
    /Volumes/MacOs_disk/AOSP/android-6.0.0_r6/prebuilts/android-emulator/darwin-x86_64/emulator64-arm -android-hw /Volumes/MacOs_disk/AOSP/android-6.0.0_r6.tmp/build_out/target/product/generic/hardware-qemu.ini
    emulator: registered 'boot-properties' qemud service
    emulator: Using kernel serial device prefix: ttyS
    emulator: Ramdisk image contains fstab.goldfish file
    emulator: Found format of system partition: 'ext4'
    emulator: Found format of userdata partition: 'ext4'
    emulator: Found format of cache partition: 'ext4'
    emulator: system partition format: ext4
    emulator: Mapping 'system' partition image to /tmp/android-tom/emulator-kBISGe
    emulator: nand_add_dev: system,size=0x60000000,file=/tmp/android-tom/emulator-kBISGe,initfile=/Volumes/MacOs_disk/AOSP/android-6.0.0_r6.tmp/build_out/target/product/generic/system.img,pagesize=512,extrasize=0
    emulator: userdata partition format: ext4
    emulator: nand_add_dev: userdata,size=0x22600000,file=/Volumes/MacOs_disk/AOSP/android-6.0.0_r6.tmp/build_out/target/product/generic/userdata-qemu.img,pagesize=512,extrasize=0
    emulator: cache partition format: ext4
    emulator: nand_add_dev: cache,size=0x4200000,file=/Volumes/MacOs_disk/AOSP/android-6.0.0_r6.tmp/build_out/target/product/generic/cache.img,pagesize=512,extrasize=0
    emulator: registered 'boot-properties' qemud service
    emulator: Adding boot property: 'dalvik.vm.heapsize' = '48m'
    emulator: Adding boot property: 'ro.config.low_ram' = 'true'
    emulator: Adding boot property: 'qemu.sf.lcd_density' = '160'
    emulator: Adding boot property: 'qemu.hw.mainkeys' = '1'
    emulator: Adding boot property: 'qemu.sf.fake_camera' = 'back'
    emulator: Kernel parameters: qemu.gles=0 qemu=1 console=ttyS0 android.qemud=ttyS1 androidboot.hardware=goldfish android.checkjni=1 ndns=1
    emulator: autoconfig: -scale 1
    emulator: Forcing ro.adb.qemud to "0".
    emulator: control console listening on port 5554, ADB on port 5555
    emulator: sent '0012host:emulator:5555' to ADB server
    emulator: setting up http proxy:  server=127.0.0.1 port=8889
    emulator: android_hw_fingerprint_init: fingerprint qemud listen service initialized

    emulator: ping program: /Volumes/MacOs_disk/AOSP/android-6.0.0_r6/prebuilts/android-emulator/darwin-x86_64/ddms
    goldfish_fb_get_pixel_format:170: display surface,pixel format:
      bits/pixel:  16
      bytes/pixel: 2
      depth:       16
      red:         bits=5 mask=0xf800 shift=11 max=0x1f
      green:       bits=6 mask=0x7e0 shift=5 max=0x3f
      blue:        bits=5 mask=0x1f shift=0 max=0x1f
      alpha:       bits=0 mask=0x0 shift=0 max=0x0
    emulator: ### WARNING: /etc/localtime does not point to /usr/share/zoneinfo/, can't determine zoneinfo timezone name
    emulator: _hwFingerprint_connect: connect finger print listen is called

    emulator: got message from guest system fingerprint HAL

    emulator: User configuration saved to /Users/tom/.android/emulator-user.ini
    ```

**In a word, I want to compile my own android 6.0 image and then use this image to run the emulator on mac m1**

**In a word, I want to compile my own android 6.0 image and then use this image to run the emulator on mac m1**

Comment: I think , exist same way to build aosp and run it on mac m1 . Because AndroidStudio can download the android 6.0 img and run it . Just i don't know how to do it . If you know please help me . thank you ...